# Is it possible to add anothersite.com/myownhomepage to my own django urls.py

Tags: python, html, django

websiteI have two static ip (x.com'which is in simple html',y.com'django framwork')..I just want to compatible with x.com/foo to y.com's login page......

That means if someone trying to excess x.com/foo on address-bar, it should open y.com's homepage..I know we can add a hipper link in x.com page.But I cant do that for some reason..
What I have to write in y.com's urls.py??

Here is my y.com's urls.py

```
url(r'^$',login),  # login is my y.com's homepage
url(r'^login/',login),
```

Note: I am using django 1.6 for y.com & x.com is in simple html website. Thanks in advance....

Comment: You can't with django and other web frameworks. You need to redirect people from `x.com/foo` to `y.com`.

Comment: Thanks for reply... So Its not possible..Is there a way not to show in x.com's web page a link of y.com/homepage,but it will do so